# Is "too complex" evidence useless?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, complexity, philosophy-of-social-sciences

Is "too complex" evidence useless?

E.g. studies on social phenomena, which are *really complicated*. The reason they are *really complicated* are e.g.:

- If they study people, then their cognition allows adapting new strategies, or "changing of opinion". Thus a study that was concluded at some time may fail to exist or have the same form at a later time. Thus such study might not attain *consistency*.

On the other hand:

- The studies may display "situational truth", which means that "it applies, when it applies, but it doesn't apply always". Though the understanding of "when it applies" might still be complicated. In this sense "consistency" may not even be required, but then the "nature" of the data is of different sorts.

Further,

- What principles and methods are "trustworthy" for such complex
  evidence?
- Is it possible that methodologies themselves also contain error?
- So where does the feasibility of utilizing "complex evidence" lie?

Comment: It is not useless, it is just more costly to utilize. It requires massive aggregation and processing of data over multiple situations to detect persisting patterns and separate them from situational variations. This is why Big Data is such a hot topic now, there is no other choice if one is to study complex phenomena with multiple and often *a priori* unidentified significant influence factors. Variation over time is a separate issue.

Comment: @Conifold Good point about big data, I've thought the same.

Comment: Ironically, I would estimate that the answer to this question is very complicated. Especially since there are several sub questions. I would think that a full answer might fill a fairly largish book.

Answer (score 1):

As I often like to say, the division between the 'hard' (physical) sciences and the 'soft' (social) sciences is a category error, or at least a gross misnomer. The real distinction is between the *easy* sciences (like physics or chemistry) and the *hard* sciences (like psychology or sociology). The physical sciences are comparatively easy because in the physical sciences (not entirely mutually exclusive):

- It is generally possible to isolate simple, independent variables
- Error terms are generally small, and normalize well
- It is usually possible to make gross reductions and approximations without sacrificing power (e.g., to use forces operating on center of mass, thus avoiding the problem of calculating forces applied to objects with complex shapes and densities)
- Objects of study do not (as a rule) react to the condition of being studied

Where the physical sciences violate any of these conditions — e.g., turbulent flow, quantum theory, non-linear (fractal) dynamics, etc — it becomes almost as hard to get clear and clean results as it is in the social sciences. Imagine what would happen to Newton's Law of Gravity if massy objects 'decided' on a case by case basis whether they would obey it, or even just if objects responded to gravitational force in a complex, non-differentiable manner (e.g., if combining different materials in different compounds and alloys would change their gravitational behavior). Then Newton's physics would be *hard*.

Social phenomena are (in fact) extremely complicated; far more complicated than most things one will find in the physical realm. That does not make them less scientific, or less important. It merely means that we have difficulty separating out independent variables, and that out inability to control for a wide range of important variables will increase our error terms. Further, we must be aware of the fact that social science *results* can leach back into the public realm and change the very thing they are studying: think of the way Freudian psychology has reconfigured public understanding of the human mind, and the impact that has had on social attitudes and behaviors. The falsificationist model was a poor model to begin with, even for simplistic aspects of the physical sciences. It simply cannot be used with more difficult, complex systems.

The real issue here, I think, is that people like Popper were trying very hard to separate the sciences from the *moral* aspects of human existence (as though building a nuclear weapon is merely a matter of technical know-how, without regard for the social purpose or ramifications of such a device). To that early 20th century mindset, morality was a function of religion, and religion was anathema to science. That separation is impossible in the social sciences. One cannot study (say) the roots of genocide while studiously ignoring the moral questions genocide raises; one can only study it with an eye to preventing (or in some disreputable cases encouraging) the act of genocide. Where the physical sciences aim to create new material principle the social sciences aim to create new social principles, but new social principles threaten the social status quo, and threaten to embroil science in messy human moral conflicts. Popper and others of his era wanted to keep science 'pure': free of the taint of human morality and emotions. But as the debacles of evolution and climate science have taught us, reaching for the ideal of 'pure' science is naïve at best.

Comment: I found that a good read.

Comment: Do you presuppose that there needs to be more exact empirical psychological methodology in order to use science to decide for "value choices" for example? So even if there's machine learning et all to go through data, unless there exists a precise explanation of value choice/opinion etc., then what does it mean? This is my main criticism in dealing with complex social phenomena in the first place. If they cannot be explained with little ambiguity, then they're always inconclusive?

Comment: @mavavilj — methodology *is* science: exact or inexact, conclusive or inconclusive, 'doing science' means adopting a consistent methodology to examine a problem. We have very little idea what 'gravity' is, but that does not stop us from applying Newton's laws; why aren't you concerned about that ambiguity?

Comment: @TedWrigley I'm concerned about *demarcation problem*. That is, where science starts and where it's too vague to be called science. Reason to be concerned: the word "science" as well as scientific tools may have semantic implications of: correctness, truthfulness, ... to some, even when the study would be "vague". I wrote this short text because of this: http://noncontradictingphilosophy.blogspot.com/2020/01/theres-science-and-theres-scientific.html In the context of complex data, there may be the problem of "reaching a level to be called 'science'" and "knowing about error".

Comment: Further, there are cognitive phenomena such as "appeal to complexity", which may cause people to interpret vague data in vague ways. Thus the problem of "drawing a line between science and something else" may become a problem. I've also seen examples where using scientific methodology may actually lead to understanding less of the real phenomenon, because the "methodology" manipulates people's perceptions about the phenomenon. E.g. do statistical filters increase or decrease value of "subjectively opinionated data"?

Comment: @TedWrigley Physicalist phenomena are intuitively easier than e.g. social, because physicalist phenomena often change slowly, whereas subjective, social phenomena like opinions may change very quickly. Therefore also, the complexity is not just in data that has been gathered, but also, "when and how often to gather data".

Comment: @mavavilj — The 'demarcation problem' (as Wittgenstein might have put it) is an empty referent: a mistake in language that ought to be redacted rather than pursued. It puts an abstract concept of 'Science' ahead of the actual practice of science in a way that undercuts the true power of scientific investigation. Science does not need to 'demarcate' itself; people merely need to apply scientific principles to whatever they are studying, and science takes care of itself.

Comment: @mavavilj — You are making a sociopolitical argument about the public misinterpretation of the abstract concept 'Science,' and I won't dispute that problematic, but you will not change that public misconception by reinforcing the notion of an abstract concept 'Science' any more than you will put out a kitchen fire by throwing cooking grease on it. The only way to end public confusion and misperception is to double down on the *practice* of science, and let the fire burn out from lack of fuel.

Comment: @mavavilj — I stand by my bullet points for why physical science are easier than social ones. Your points are covered by my fourth bullet point, I think.  Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I am in no way a specialist of social science, but your question makes me think of the Duhem Quine thesis.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhem%E2%80%93Quine_thesis

The idea is that hypothesis can not be tested individually, but always in bundle. The canonical example being the discovery of Jupiter's satellites by Galileo: his discovery is valid only under the hypothesis that his telescope did not produce visual artifacts he could have mistaken for satellites. Some rivals actually argued that it was the case.

Social science evidence, just like astronomy evidence, is collected using tools. Those tools are nowhere as simple as a telescope, but involve polling techniques, interviews, statistics, all of which are built on hypothesis that bundle with the main hypothesis your evidence was collected in order to test.

In order to validate the hypothesis that the telescope does not produce artifact, it is easy enough to exhibit it, or its blueprints, and explain the optics involved in the magnification. On the other hand, to prove that a large corpus of interviews or polls demonstrate what it is intended to, the researchers have to collect loads of meta-data: in what conditions the interviews were conducted, what measures were taken to avoid bias, or loaded questions in the polls, etc...

A good example might be the results of opinion polls as they are published in the newspapers: all too often a close inspection of the methodology shows biases that are not disclosed in the paper.

The point being, complex evidence (data) comes with loads of assumptions that have to be accounted for and documented (metadata). All the data has to be understood and agreed on along with the metadata, otherwise it is effectively useless.